# PSN Wallet top up card

Tags: psn

I'm wanting to buy a PSN Wallet top up card from the UK and send that redeem code over to a guy in California. Would UK money on that card work on his PS4 in California if you know what i mean?

Answer (score 1):

***No.***

via the [PlayStation Community](http://community.us.playstation.com/t5/PlayStation-Network-Support/Can-i-use-foreign-PSN-card-codes/td-p/44900411)

User "emerald swords" wrote in 2009:

> PSN cards are region locked. You will need to buy a card associated
>   with your region.  DLC's are also region locked.   I've used this site
>   several times for obtaining codes out of my region, works very well!

This was [again verified](http://community.us.playstation.com/t5/PlayStation-Network-Support/Can-I-use-psn-cards-in-another-country/td-p/37456757) by a pro level community supporter, "Brit-Ko" in 2010:

> No PSN cards from one country will not work in another, for example a
>   USA PSN card will not work in the UK & vice versa, having said that if
>   the country was an EU country then an EU PSN card would work in a
>   number of countries, make sense?

You'll have to purchase a PSN card from the region the recipient will use it.